# Save a copy of a large response stream to file on web server

Tags: asp.net, .net, xmlwriter

I have a large XML file that I'm producing from an SQL database and streaming to the client's web browser using the System.Xml.XmlWriter object.  The problem is, every time a user hits the web page, the 170MB file is produced in the DB and transfered again.

I would like to stream the file to the user so they get it as quick as possible, and then save the result to a file on the web server.  Future requests would then check first to see if the file exists. If it does, it would send the file instead of calling the DB.

My question:  How would I store what was written to the Response.Output object to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a buffer, save part of the data to the buffer, and at the same time send them and save them... here is an example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int sourceBytes;
do
{
    // read it - or fix the buffer content
    sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // out put to the client
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
    // saved it to the file.
    sWriter.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);

} while (sourceBytes > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var filePath = "c:\\temp\\file.dat";
if(System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
  using(var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
     WriteToResponseStream(stream);
}
else
{
    byte[] file = GetFileFromDb();
    WriteToResponseStream(new MemoryStream(file));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, file)
}
```